# Adding price of product records with same name in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, logic, javascript-objects

Well, I need to add price of products with same name and modify the array accordingly.

Input: `records=[{'name':'A', 'price':200},{'name':'B', 'price':350},{'name':'A', 'price':150},{'name':'B', 'price':300}]`

Output: `records=[{'name':'A', 'price':350},{'name':'B', 'price':650}]`

Will be glad if the solution is provided using javascript forEach function.

Comment: You should do your homework yourself! :)

Comment: just use push this data in array  I think that will serve urs purpose

Comment: You should learn Array method. ('forEach' and 'push')

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a new array with the wanted objects and add the price to the grouped item, with a reference from this object.

```js
var records = [{ 'name': 'A', 'price': 200 }, { 'name': 'B', 'price': 350 }, { 'name': 'A', 'price': 150 }, { 'name': 'B', 'price': 300 }],
    result = [];

records.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.name]) {
        this[a.name] = { name: a.name, price: 0 };
        result.push(this[a.name]);
    }
    this[a.name].price += a.price;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it

```
records.map(function(element, index, array){
    return {
        name: element.name, 
        price: (array
            .reduceRight(function(previousvalue, currentvalue, currentindex){
                var dup = currentvalue.name === element.name;
                var cp = dup? currentvalue.price: 0;
                dup? array.splice(currentindex, 1):0;
                return previousvalue + cp;
            }, 0))}
}).filter(function(element){ return typeof element !== "undefined";});
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sfy2p1rf/1/

Comment: Yes it does. I've added a fiddle